# SlideToggle does not working in menu

Tags: jquery, menu, slidetoggle

I want to make a webshop, when I clicking to a menu link I want to show the sub menus using jquery. I made the following code:

```
$("#product_list li a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var sub_menu = $(this).next('.sub-menu');
  $('.sub-menu:visible').not(sub_menu).slideToggle('fast');
  sub_menu.slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Here is the menu what I wanted to show/hide:

```
 <ul id="product_list">
            <li class="product_list_item"><a href="#" class="product_list_item_link">Tábla PC</a> 
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="sub_product_list_item"><a href="tablet.html" class="sub_product_list_item_link">Táblák</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_product_list_item"><a href="tablet.html" class="sub_product_list_item_link">Kiegészítők</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="product_list_item"><a href="#" id="notebook" class="product_list_item_link">Notebook</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="sub_product_list_item"><a href="tablet.html" class="sub_product_list_item_link">Notebook</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_product_list_item"><a href="tablet.html" class="sub_product_list_item_link">Netbook</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_product_list_item"><a href="tablet.html" class="sub_product_list_item_link">Ultrabook</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_product_list_item"><a href="tablet.html" class="sub_product_list_item_link">Táska</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_product_list_item"><a href="tablet.html" class="sub_product_list_item_link">Töltő</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_product_list_item"><a href="tablet.html" class="sub_product_list_item_link">Dokkoló</a></li>
                    <li class="sub_product_list_item"><a href="tablet.html" class="sub_product_list_item_link">Akkumulátor</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
 </ul>
```

I checked a many forums and it shoud be work fine, but it is not working.... Does anyone any idea why not working?

Here is the link for my [preliminary website](http://webstore.mauritiusbeachhouses.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use that `ID` as a selctor for your click:

Try like `>` [parent-child](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector with class selector:

```
$(".product_list_item > a").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var sub_menu = $(this).next('.sub-menu');
       $('.sub-menu:visible').not(sub_menu).slideToggle('fast');
       sub_menu.slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Or try this

```
$(".product_list_item a").click(function(e){
    if(e.target.id != ""){
       var sub_menu = $(this).next('.sub-menu');
       $('.sub-menu:visible').not(sub_menu).slideToggle('fast');
       sub_menu.slideToggle('fast');
    }
    else
       e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/H9mef/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(".product_list_item a").click(function(e){  
var sub_menu = $(this).next('.sub-menu');
$('.sub-menu:visible').not(sub_menu).slideToggle('fast');
sub_menu.slideToggle('fast');
});
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/PgzrU/62/)

Hope It will help you